# Why are some rabbinic fasts daylight and tisha b'av is full day?

Tags: fast-days

The 4 minor fasts and Tisha B'Av are rabbinic.  Why is only one rabbinic fast a full day and the other rabbinic fasts are daylight fasts rather than full day?

Answer (score 1):

Shulchan Aruch [550:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.550.2?lang=he&p2=Mishnah_Berurah.550.7&lang2=he) states the difference;

> צומות הללו חוץ מט' באב מותרים ברחיצה וסיכה ונעיל' הסנדל ותשמיש המטה ואין צריך להפסיק בהם מבעוד יום

The MB 550:6-7 explains that it would be too much on the Tzibbur to have the full restrictions on every fast so it was limited to Tisha Ba'v

> דבשעה שרצו וקבלו עליהם לצום בכל הארבע תענית הנ"ל לא קבלו עליהם שיהיו בחומר ת"צ כט"ב לפי שאין רוב הצבור יכולין לעמוד בה ובעל נפש יחמיר בכולן כמו בט"ב

However if one went to sleep without thinking of waking up before sunrise, it is considered as if he accepted the fast and can no longer eat. So the fact that it starts at sunrise is a leniency and it can indeed start earlier. This halacha is brought in Shulchan Aruch [564:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.564.1?lang=he&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=he) and is based on a Gemara [Taanis 12A](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.12a.10?lang=he)

> כל תענית שאוכלים בו בלילה בין צבור בין יחיד הרי זה אוכל ושותה עד שיעלה עמוד השחר והוא שלא ישן (שינת קבע) (טור) אבל אם ישן (שינת קבע) אינו חוזר ואוכל ולא שותה אא"כ התנה לאכול או לשתות: הגה ויש אומרים דבשתייה אין צריך תנאי דמסתמא דעתו של אדם לשתייה אחר השינה והוי כאלו התנה (טור ומרדכי והגהות מיימוני והגהות אשירי)